# MSys2 64bit gdb gives python error and doesn't work

Tags: python, c, gdb, mingw, msys2

Recently installed mingw, gdb and gcc using MSys2 as supposed to but the debugger doesn't work under VisualStudio Code nor from cmd/powershell. I tried to delete PYTHONPATH enviromental variable as it solved it for some but not for me.

Everything other works fine, python too.

It gives me a strange error if i want to do `gdb --version` :

```
C:\Users\cseh_>gdb --version
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310'
  program name = 'c:\msys64\mingw64/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'c:\\msys64\\mingw64/bin/python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'c:\\msys64\\mingw64/bin/python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
    'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\python310.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\python3.10',
    'C:\\Users\\cseh_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\python3.10\\lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002a90 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Update: I tried to unset the 'Other Python' from the variables inside the MSys2 Shell, got to somewhere but still no luck.

```
cseh_@Develop08 MSYS ~
$ printenv
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
!::=::\
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.6.2
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/lib/pkgconfig
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DEVELOP08
HOSTNAME=Develop08
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM=MSYS
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ORIGINAL_TEMP=/c/Users/cseh_/AppData/Local/Temp
OS=Windows_NT
HOMEDRIVE=C:
MSYSTEM_CARCH=x86_64
USERDOMAIN=DEVELOP08
PWD=/home/cseh_
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\cseh_
MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man
PRINTER=Xerox B210 (XRX9C934EAD9213)
TZ=Europe/Budapest
tmp=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Temp
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_PATH=/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
HOME=/home/cseh_
USERNAME=cseh_
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
OneDrive=C:\Users\cseh_\OneDrive
COMSPEC=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
APPDATA=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Roaming
SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME=DEVELOP08
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info
PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
TERM=xterm
LOGONSERVER=\\DEVELOP08
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
PYTHONHOME=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
USER=cseh_
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
TEMP=/tmp
temp=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Temp
MSYSTEM_CHOST=x86_64-pc-msys
ORIGINAL_TMP=/c/Users/cseh_/AppData/Local/Temp
SHLVL=1
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8c01
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
SESSIONNAME=Console
PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
HOMEPATH=\Users\cseh_
MSYSCON=mintty.exe
TMP=/tmp
CONFIG_SITE=/etc/config.site
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/usr
WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
OLDPWD=/
GOPATH=C:\Users\cseh_\go
TERM_PROGRAM=mintty
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
_=/usr/bin/printenv

cseh_@Develop08 MSYS ~
$ unset PYTHONHOME

cseh_@Develop08 MSYS ~
$ unset PYTHONPATH

cseh_@Develop08 MSYS ~
$ printenv
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
!::=::\
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.6.2
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/lib/pkgconfig
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DEVELOP08
HOSTNAME=Develop08
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM=MSYS
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ORIGINAL_TEMP=/c/Users/cseh_/AppData/Local/Temp
OS=Windows_NT
HOMEDRIVE=C:
MSYSTEM_CARCH=x86_64
USERDOMAIN=DEVELOP08
PWD=/home/cseh_
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\cseh_
MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man
PRINTER=Xerox B210 (XRX9C934EAD9213)
TZ=Europe/Budapest
tmp=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Temp
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_PATH=/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
HOME=/home/cseh_
USERNAME=cseh_
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
OneDrive=C:\Users\cseh_\OneDrive
COMSPEC=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
APPDATA=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Roaming
SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME=DEVELOP08
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info
TERM=xterm
LOGONSERVER=\\DEVELOP08
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
USER=cseh_
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
TEMP=/tmp
temp=C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Temp
MSYSTEM_CHOST=x86_64-pc-msys
ORIGINAL_TMP=/c/Users/cseh_/AppData/Local/Temp
SHLVL=1
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8c01
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
SESSIONNAME=Console
PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
HOMEPATH=\Users\cseh_
MSYSCON=mintty.exe
TMP=/tmp
CONFIG_SITE=/etc/config.site
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/usr
WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
OLDPWD=/
GOPATH=C:\Users\cseh_\go
TERM_PROGRAM=mintty
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: It seems to pick up two different python versions. Try removing the one in `AppData` from the PATH.

Comment: But that's the only one in the PATH.
It contains the following:
`C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`

And then there is outside the PATH but still in system variables:
Variable name: `PYTHONHOME`
Variable value: `C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`

Variable name: `PYTHONPATH`
Variable value: `C:\Users\cseh_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`

Comment: MSYS2 has its own python, and it has better chances of working with its own gdb. I would remove all traces of the other python from env variables (at least for gdb, not necessarily globally).

Comment: I don't want to remove the other python globally because i want to use it. How can i remove it for only the gdb? Thanks btw.

Comment: Try MSYS2 shell, it should have a clean PATH. Not sure about other env variables (check with `printenv`). If they're still there, unset them with `unset PYTHONHOME` and so on.

Comment: I tried it, see the changes in the editet question but it still gives me an error. I don't know how to unset the two python lines from the path but as you can see i succeeded with `unset PYTHONHOME` and with `unset PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: MSYS2 has its own clean PATH, there's no Python in there. You're running the wrong shell though (since your debugger is in `mingw64/bin`, you need `c:\msys64\mingw64.exe`; unset those two variables, and try running gdb from there).

Comment: Thank you, it finally works! Only problem remains is that i cannot use it anywhere else for eg. in VS Code or else. Can i make it permanent or globally without losing python?

Comment: Does your python not work without the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables? It's usually not necessary to set them.

Comment: If i remember correctly i needed to set it because of pygame doesn't worked without it in VS Code.

Comment: Is it possible to add arguments in VS code when it calls gdb? In that case you could try to change it to `gdb -eiex "set python ignore-environment on"`, with this gdb would never use the python environment variables.

Comment: I tried it in the launch.json file but gives me an error "Value expected jsonc(516)".

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Maybe show your launch.json file.